# To show or not to show an alert on closing the Window at particular situations

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, nstextfield

I am using some text fields and web view in a window. What I want is if user makes any changes in any of the text fields or the webView then on closing the window it should show an alert to save the changes made (and this is done)...

But what I want to do is if the user does not make any changes in the any of the fields or web View then on closing the window , it should close without showing any alert.Please let me know how this can be done.

And let me know if this is not clear so that I can give some more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `NSDocument` based application you can use this.

```
- (BOOL)isDocumentEdited
```

Return `YES` If you want  to save the change otherwise `NO`.

Here is the Class reference for [NSDocument](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsdocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply...but this is NSApplication based application.Is there any method to achieve this ?